# primefaces: dynamic value for oncomplete attribute of ajax component

Tags: primefaces

I passed dynamic  value for oncomplete attribute

is this correct way to do? (not working)

```
oncomplete="if(myBean.isValid){Confirmation.show()}"/>
```

Comment: try: oncomplete="#{buyerDelegateBean.valid eq true? stDateConfirmation.show():...}  "/>

Comment: @RongNK whats is the difference between your comment and freak's answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no , this is wrong.Try this

`oncomplete="{buyerDelegateBean.valid eq 'true'?Confirmation.show():'else logic'}"/>`

I hope `valid` is a boolean value in your code snippet

Comment: thanks. It is good. I applied this for a dateSelect event.so a small issue with my code. Now it is fine.